# Apache .htaccess convert http uri to https causing redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I know this question has been asked a thousand times, but I cannot seem to find the answer.

We have a website hosted by 123-reg's shared web hosting package (no access to http config files).  I have added ssl to the site, and the certificate works when directly requesting using https.

The problem arises when I try to redirect everything from http to https using the .htaccess file.

First I tried the SERVER_PORT variable in the condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This does not work as the https redirect request uses port 80 also (I am querying this with 123-reg at the moment). The condition is always met and causes a redirect loop.

Next I tried the HTTPS variable:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This condition is always met as the variable is never set to on (and causes a redirect loop).  I wonder if this is to do with the port no = 80 for https.

I found two server variables, SSL and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL, which do change from "" to 1, but only when I delete the .htaccess file and *directly* request http or https.

If I try and use the SSL or HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL variables in the RewriteCond condition, it causes a redirect loop.

I cannot see the variables while the redirect loop is happening, so I do not know if they are being changed during the re-direct.

---

edit:

I have found the answer.  I was using:

```
RewriteCond %{SSL} !1
```

which should be:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL} !1
```