# .htaccess file not redirecting http://www. to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, web, https

I have made a .htaccess file to redirect all website traffic to `https://www.`.

**This is my complete .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The below redirects work exactly as expected:

```
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
```

**Except:**

```
http://www.example.com -> http://www.example.com
```

As shown above, if you go to `http://www.` it doesn't redirect to the HTTPS version.

Can anyone help me understand why the other redirects are working fine, but that one is not?

Additional Notes: *I have looked at a number of posts on StackOverflow, but most of their solutions end in redirect loop errors.*

Comment: Regarding the "redirect loop" - How is the SSL cert managed?

Comment: @w3dk The SSL certificate is managed by my website hosting company (123-Reg). It has been purchased to cover www.example.com. It isn't a wildcard.

Comment: I assume it's just a typo, but `http://www.example.com -> http://www.example.com` should presumably be `http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com` (with an `s`). And the preceding "redirect" `https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com` isn't a redirect at all, as _nothing_ should be happening in this instance.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make that clear.

I put `http://www.example.com -> http://www.example.com` to show what was happening, not what I desired to happen! So yes, I want `http://www.` to redirect to `https://www.`.

Comment: Basically, I want everything to redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting 123-Reg (my hosting provider), they submitted this solution, which works perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Basically they have set the script to do two tasks: Change domain to `WWW`, if it isn't already, THEN change to `HTTPS`. Also, they used `ENV:HTTPS`, which is different to what was found in their documentation (`ENV:SSL`).

Glad to have to this sorted, and maybe this will help out others using 123-Reg Hosting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, the solution presented by 123-Reg is not yet optimal. The first RewriteRule should redirect to HTTPS, otherwise you'll get an unnecessary double redirect when requesting `http://example.com`. The second RewriteRule should be a 301 otherwise it doesn't send the correct msg to search engines and browsers won't cache it. The NC flag on the first RewriteRule is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

As you have found, this won't redirect when requesting the canonical hostname (ie. `www.example.com`) regardless of whether it is HTTP or HTTPS.

You need to change this to something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will trigger a redirect to the canonical URL if HTTPS is "off" *or* it's not the canonical hostname.

> ...but most of their solutions end in redirect loop errors.

If you are behind a proxy (eg. CloudFlare) that is managing your SSL cert then this could still result in a redirect loop because the connection between you and the proxy might be HTTP, not HTTPS. This would mean that your server only serves content over HTTP, not HTTPS. If this is the case then there are additional headers that can be checked on the request (eg. `X-Forwarded-Proto`) or set a "page rule" in the case of CloudFlare (Flexible SSL - free service).

---

**UPDATE#1:** [123-Reg provide a help document regarding SSL](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/securing-ssl-access-to-your-website-4141/). It seems they set an `SSL` environment variable when "the connection is SSL-secured". This would mean that you could potentially do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is, however, non-standard and "unique" to 123-Reg. (*Aside:* The PHP code suggestion in the 123-Reg linked document is not the recommended way to check the environment variable, as this would result in an E_NOTICE if the variable is not set!?)

You should also ensure your browser cache is cleared before testing.

**UPDATE#2: To help with debugging...** to find out what values are being returned, you could assign some Apache values to environment variables and check the values of these in your server-side script (eg. PHP?). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=APACHE_HTTPS:%1]

# You don't really need this, but for completeness...
RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL} (.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=APACHE_SSL:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} (.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=APACHE_PROTO:%1]
```

Then check the environment variables `APACHE_HTTPS`, `APACHE_SSL` and `APACHE_PROTO` in your server-side script. (eg. in PHP, use the [getenv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @w3dk. 

I implemented your suggestion like this: 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

After testing different methods, whenever the [OR] statement is implemented, the redirect error occurs.

If it is removed, there are no redirect errors, but it still doesn't redirect `http://www.`

Comment: If you've purchased an SSL cert to cover your domain (I assume this must cover both `example.com` and `www.example.com`) then you would not expect to have to check `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}`. And you certainly should not be checking both `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` _and_ `%{HTTPS}` - these are mutually exclusive. I've updated my answer with respect to 123-Reg - a different method maybe required.

Comment: I really appricated your time with this issue @w3dk. I have used what you found along with this post -
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310560/apache-htaccess-convert-http-uri-to-https-causing-redirect-loop

Unfortunately I am still getting the same "www.example.com redirected you too many times." error message whenever I add in line about HTTPS or the [OR] statement :(
P.S. I have been using incognito and difference browsers to combat cache.

Comment: This is what I tried: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL} !1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I have got in touch with 123-Reg to see if they can help me any further with this.

Comment: The redirect loop does imply the SSL-state is not being detected. You need the `OR` flag in order to redirect all cases. Without the `OR` flag, it is an implied AND, so in theory it would only redirect if HTTP _AND_ not `www.example.com`. I have updated my answer with some code to help with debugging.

Comment: @frostluke Did 123-Reg get back to you?

Comment: I have submitted the response from 123-Reg as the answer. It was not far off what you had suggested. They used `ENV:HTTPS` rather than `ENV:SSL` and also separated it into two steps. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After lots of issues with 123 Reg and redirecting all versions of pages to single relevant https page with Wordpress, this is what has worked for me across multiple sites now and has proven effective in terms of SEO.  Hope it helps!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This is identical to the code presented in the accepted answer. But also, you should avoid editing the code in the `# BEGIN WordPress` section as WordPress itself tries to manage this section and your custom directives can get overwritten.