# HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working with existing rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been at this for 3 days now with no results!

I have an existing http site which has lots of redirect rules depending on URL friendly links which I now need to force load to https - Google will eventually drop them from the index but there are lots of links to the pages from 3rd party sites which I cannot physically change.

The .htaccess below handles http://example.com, but obviously not http://www.example.com

The problem is that if I add in a rewrite and get it to specifically change the url prefix to https it either doesn't work at all or will forward to https://www.example.com but then give an error message as too many redirects (depending on which version of http to https I've tried).

I've also tried splitting the code up to first check for https/redirect, and then non-www, but again when it does forward properly it either creates a loop or strips off the original query.

Help! lol

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^2/Home https://www.example.co.uk/  [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?docid=$1&docname=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^item/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ item.php?prodid=$1&prodname=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^search/ store.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^store/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ store.php?catid=$1&startPage=$2&limitPerPage=$3&searchTerm=$4 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^store/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ store.php?catid=$1&startPage=$2&limitPerPage=$3 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^store/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ store.php?catid=$1&catname=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ sitemap.php

    ErrorDocument 404 /15/Error

    AddType application/x-font-woff2 .woff2

    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl*" block_bad_bots
    Deny from env=block_bad_bots

    #6 month for image files
    <filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15552000, public"
    </filesMatch>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000

    # 6 month for css and js
    <filesMatch ".(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15552000, public"
    </filesMatch>

    # long expire
    <filesMatch ".(woff2)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=102628000, public"
    </filesMatch>

    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #Enable Gzip compression
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/eot
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

    # Remove browser bugs for legacy browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On

    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

    # Video
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

    # CSS, JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

    # Others
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't currently have an HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the `.htaccess` code your posted, so it's anyone's guess why it was not working for you.

But you would need something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess`, immediately following the `RewriteBase` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is a "standard" HTTP to HTTPS redirect. However, whether this works or not (and results in a redirect loop) can depend on how HTTPS is managed/implemented on your server. For example, whether you are using a front-end proxy (eg. Cloudflare FREE) that manages your SSL?

If you are using a front-end proxy then you may need to change it to something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or, some shared hosts use an `HTTPS` *environment* variable, instead of the `HTTPS` *server* variable, as used in the first example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:** This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368725/htaccess-file-not-redirecting-http-www-to-https-www) from 2017 suggests something similar to the above for use with the host "123-reg" (having heard back from 123-reg themselves). They've used the *CondPattern* `!=on`, which shouldn't really make any difference, unless 123-reg are doing something a bit odd?! The `HTTPS` *environment* (and similarly named *server*) variable(s) should contain either the string "off" or "on". So, it really shouldn't matter whether you check `off` or `!on` - the result *should* be the same.

NB: First test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to make sure it's working OK - this is to avoid any potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

> **UPDATE:** The site is on shared hosting with 123-reg

[This 123-reg support page](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/hosting/securing-ssl-access-to-your-website/) states:

> On our Linux shared hosting accounts, the environment variable SSL will be set when the connection is SSL-secured.

If this is the case, then you should be able to do the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above redirects to HTTPS if the `SSL` env var is empty (ie. not set).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (http to https is omitted from my code as it breaks!) - I tried your suggestions: the first 2 redirect to https, but then I get the dreaded "your page isn't forwarding correctly" message. When I try the 3rd, nothing happens. The site is on shared hosting with 123-reg

Comment: 123-reg appears to use an `SSL` env var instead. I've updated my answer. (If this is the case then this is reasonably unique to 123-reg.) It would be interesting to know exactly what the `SSL` env var is set to (whether it has a specific/meaningful value or is simply `1` or _empty_). You can examine these env vars in your PHP code.

Comment: OK. Tried it - forwards ok but then just stuck in the loop again. Tried it after deleting the 4th and 5th lines of my original code above - still same :-(

Comment: Presumably (without the redirect) `https://www.example.com/...` works OK if you request it directly? Please check for an `SSL` env var when requesting HTTP and HTTPS. Check the HTTP traffic in the browser... what redirects do you see exactly when implementing the above redirect? Is it repeatedly trying to redirect to HTTPS or is it being redirected back to HTTP then HTTPS then HTTP then HTTPS? (The 4th and 5th lines are still required to canonicalise the www subdomain and should  not cause any problems with this.)

Comment: This [related question from a couple of years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368725/htaccess-file-not-redirecting-http-www-to-https-www), also using 123-reg, appear to have a working solution (as suggested by 123-reg themselves) that uses the `HTTPS` _env var_ ie. `%{ENV:HTTPS}` - however, this is something we have already tried above (although with a different regex/_CondPattern_)?! If this is causing a redirect loop then it implies the `HTTPS` env var is being set by the host, but is always set to "off" - which is strange. I think there must be _something else_ going on here?

Comment: Hurrah! The solution in the related question worked! ie, using !=on and moving the lines below my non-www to www ones! (I'd tried moving lines previously but not that option). 123-reg haven't yet answered my query from last week, and although I searched Stackoverflow I didn't find that previous post - so thank you for your time and help, my sanity is now restored! :-)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Although I would still be interested to know what this `HTTPS` _environment_ variable actually contains when accessed over HTTP vs HTTPS. For `!=on` to work and `off` seemingly not to work in the way you describe doesn't make a whole lot of sense and strongly suggests a caching issue IMO. Also, the order of those two rules should not not make a difference in this respect - this would also perhaps suggest a caching issue? (I've used 123-reg in the past - "support" is not one of their strengths!)

Comment: The annoying thing is, I've done the http to https switch on several other sites supposedly on the same type of 123-reg hosting where the 'standard' code works. Sod's Law that when I come to switch my own site...... :-D